# Creating Innerclass with full access to local variables of outerclass

Tags: java, oop

So here's the scenario.

I have a class A, and I want some of its methods to behave differently depending on how the class is called.

What I've done now is something like this:

```
interface Interface{
  public void someMethod();
}

class A{
  int variable;
  Interface getA1(){
    return new A1();
  }
  Interface getA2(){
    return new A2();
  }
  class A1 extends A implements Interface{
    public void someMethod(){
       variable++;
    }
  }
  class A2 extends A implements Interface{
    public void someMethod(){
       variable--;
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem with this is that when getA1() or getA2() is called, it will actually return a completely new instance of A1, or A2, where the int variable is totally separate to the parent class A (duh, silly me of course thats how it works).

So the question is. Is it possible in java to return some kind of inner class that allows you to modify the data within the outer class through it's methods?

The key thing is having a single class that can return interfaces that modify that single class in different ways, depending on which method was used to create that interface.

I might be overlooking something simple here, sorry but it's got me stumped! :(

Edit: I think the better way of explaining it is - **I want to give direct access to local variables, to a subclass (or another class), and have a method in the original class that can create the other class.**

EDIT2: The reason why it created a separate instance when getA1()/getA2(), is likely because class A1 and A2 were declared to extend A. It seems like if the extends clause is removed, then it works as expected.

Comment: Unless a variable is private, subclasses will have access to it. Whether or not a factory belongs in the base class, different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes an anonymous class would do e.g.

```
interface Interface{
  public void someMethod();
}

public class A {
    int variable;

    Interface getA1() {
        return new Interface() {
            @Override
            public void someMethod() {
                variable++;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It should be pointed out though that this is equivalent to declaring non-static inner classes albeit more concise.

Comment: OH wow! it worked! Thanks! I think I overlooked it because I thought it would do the same thing as a nested class... Java works in mysterious ways...

Comment: One should note that the code is not thread safe. If two different threads call getA1().someMethod() simultaneously, for a short period of tine you cannot say exactly which value "variable" will contain.

Comment: This should work *exactly* the same if you define a full-fledged inner class.  Just because an inner class is anonymous doesn't mean that it has "special access" to its parent class's fields.  They're exactly the same.  The only difference is inner classes are named and anonymous classes aren't.

Comment: @TimPote I never said it wouldn't. My answer was in response to "The key thing is having a **single** class that can return **interfaces**...".

Comment: @Strawberry True.  But your answer implies that the OP's misunderstanding about inner classes is correct.  "it will actually return a completely new instance of A1, or A2, where the int variable is totally separate to the parent class A".  This is *totally* incorrect and your answer does not address this at all.

Comment: @TimPote, your explaination of this is exactly how I expected this to work. If you see my code however, what happens when I run it is that when someMethod() is called several times on the interface returned from getA1, and then from getA2, what I found is that the original value in A is unchanged.

Comment: The reason I had them extending the outer class is that I was a bit lazy and did not want to have to type out the methods that were common in the inner classes and the outer classes. Maybe it was the extending that was causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: also, just wanted to note that I needed to instantiate the outerclass too, which is why I did not make it abstract.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I find it *very* strange that your inner classes are extending the outer class.  I can't think of a good reason to do that and I'm not exactly sure what that even does.

Besides that, I don't understand your issue.  All inner classes have access to their parent class's fields.  For example, the following:

```
public class Tester {
  private int myInt;

  public InnerTester getInnerTester() {
    return new MyInnerTester();
  }

  public InnerTester getOtherInnerTester() {
    return new OtherInnerTester();
  }

  public interface InnerTester {
    public void doStuff();
  }

  public class MyInnerTester implements InnerTester{
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
      myInt++;
    }   
  }

  public class MyOtherInnerTester implements InnerTester {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
     myInt++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester tester = new Tester();
    System.out.println("Before: " + tester.myInt);
    tester.getInnerTester().doStuff();
    tester.getOtherInnerTester().doStuff();
    System.out.println("After: " + tester.myInt);
  }   
}
```

outputs:

```
Before: 0
After: 2
```

However, this all seems pretty shady.  I'm not exactly sure why you would want to take advantage of this behavior.  I've done similar things with action listeners before, but I wouldn't exactly call their parent object an "ActionListenerFactory".  Why don't you just have a method to increment the field on the object itself?

Comment: Hey Tim, the problem was that when you instantiate a nested class it seems to access a unique set of it's outerclass's variables (the did in my example). The method that Strawberry posted seems to avoid that though.

Comment: @Liang That's still not right.  Inner classes are tied to their parent instance.  No matter how many instances of the inner class I make, they are still tied to my original `Tester` instance and have access to his `myInt`.  See my edits to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: yep I think you are right, I think it was the fact that in my case my inner classes were extending the outer class, which caused this weird behaviour. Cheers